# Filling an array (Access violation writing location 0x00000000)

Tags: c++

My code begins to break when I want to fill `days[]`; it also breaks when I want to fill `ratio2[]`. All my arrays are declared in `main()` and initialized to `MAX`, which is defined as 50 in a global definition. I need to store a value in each index and then print it.

```
void getdata(ifstream &inFile, int id[], int days[], double ratio2[], double estmax_heart[], double ratio[], double avg[])
{
    int i; int j = 0;
    int num;
    double largest = 0;
    int n = 0;

    int max_heart = 0; int age = 0;
    double avg_comm_rate = 0; 
    double maxcomm_rate = 0;
    double exc_rate = 0;
    double sum = 0;


    while (! inFile.eof())
    {       
        inFile >> id[n];
        cout << id[n] << " ";

        inFile >> max_heart;
        cout << max_heart << " ";

        inFile >> age;
        cout << age << " " << endl;

        estmax_heart[n] = 220-age;

        ratio[n] = (max_heart/estmax_heart[n]) * 100;

        days = 0; largest = 0; sum = 0; ratio2 = 0; j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {   
            inFile >> avg_comm_rate;
            cout << avg_comm_rate << " ";

            inFile >> maxcomm_rate;
            cout << maxcomm_rate << " ";

            inFile >> exc_rate;
            cout << exc_rate << endl;

            if (exc_rate != 0)
            {
                days[i] = j + 1;        
            }

            if(maxcomm_rate > largest)
            {
                largest = maxcomm_rate;
            }

            sum = sum + avg_comm_rate;

            ratio2[i] = (largest / max_heart) * 100;
        }

        n++;    

        calculate(i, days, sum, avg_comm_rate, maxcomm_rate, exc_rate, avg, largest, estmax_heart, ratio, ratio2);

        system("pause");

        //cout << sum;
    }

    inFile.close();

    return;

}
```

Comment: As function parameters in C and C++, there is no difference between saying `int a[]` and `int* a` -- what you are passed is a pointer to the first element of the array in either case. As such, it's usually best to use the pointer syntax, as it makes it clear what you're dealing with, and helps avoid mistakes like this. Of course, in C++, there is rarely a need to use C arrays anyway -- `std::vector` and `std::array` are easier to use and less error prone, and no less efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you assign the array pointers to `0` before you access them.

```
days = 0; largest = 0; sum = 0; ratio2 = 0; j = 0;
```